# How to send a user to another webpage. Using Java Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, redirect, servlets

I have created an `index.jsp` file which uploads excel files. The `uploader.java` file will write t`hat file to a location and then I want to send the user to another webpage where they can enter the sheet number in the excel file. All the mentioned files are running individually without any errors.  When I am running the dynamic Web application I created in Eclipse, I am getting the following error:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message JSP file 

[/C:/Users/khuha/eclipse-workspace/finalApplication/src/main/webapp/sheetsdetails.jsp] not found

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/8.5.82
```

I have created a Servlet which has to redirect the user to the webpage `sheetsdetails.jsp`.
following is the code:

```
package finalApplication;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;








public class uploader extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        try {
            ServletFileUpload sf=new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory());

            List<FileItem> multifiles = sf.parseRequest(request);
            //String file="";
            String filename = null;
            for(FileItem item : multifiles)
            {
                
                filename =item.getName();
                
                item.write(new File("C:\\Users\\khuha\\eclipse-workspace\\finalApplication"+"\\"+filename));


            }
            HttpSession session=request.getSession();

            session.setAttribute("file",filename);

            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/C:\\Users\\khuha\\eclipse-workspace\\finalApplication\\src\\main\\webapp\\sheetsdetails.jsp");
            rd.forward(request,response );
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {  
            
            
            System.out.println(ex);



        }

    }

}
```

sheetsdetails.jsp:

```
<html>
<style>
body{
background: rgb(5,1,28);
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(5,1,28,1) 0%, rgba(116,85,207,1) 67%, rgba(8,2,18,1) 90%);;
color: white;
font-size: 40px;
font-family: "Verdana","sans-seriff";
}
form    {color: white;}
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-colour:white ;
  color: cyan;
  
  
 
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}




</style>


<body>

<form action="dataCollect">        
      
<label for="sheetnumber" style="position:absolute; left:415px; top:250px">Enter the sheet number you want to  look in
</label>
<input type="number" id="sheetnumber" name="sheetnumber" value="1" min="1" style="position:absolute; left:690px; top:300px; cursor: pointer;">


 <div style = "position:absolute; left:745px; top:350px; ">
 <input type="submit" name="submit">
 </div>
</form> 

<div style = "position:absolute; left:575px; top:600px; width:50px; height:10px;">
        <img src="finallogo.png" alt="logo" width=375px height=100px/>
      </div>
      
</body>

</html>
```

What I want to do:

I want to upload a file to the server and then send the user to another webpage where they select the sheet number from the uploaded excel file. Please let me kow if I am using the correct approach to do so.

P.S. this is my first time working with dynamic webapps so any resources where I can learn to send user to a webpage would be highly useful and appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not reference a jsp from disk like this:

> /C:\Users\khuha\eclipse-workspace\finalApplication\src\main\webapp\sheetsdetails.jsp

just add:

```java
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/sheetsdetails.jsp")
```

Comment: And I've forgot about a rule: "Always redirect after post". If not, the user will see the old url in the browser and when hitting the back button the user will be asked if he wants to post the data again. Or even if the user hit refresh button, I think that the the data is posted again. (I've seen that you used forward).
You can play with your initial solution to see what happens:
    RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/sheetsdetails.jsp");
    rd.forward(req, resp);

Comment: Thanks for the note I am using Redirect now